# SlickGrid 'mouseleave' event not fired when row invalidated after 'mouseenter' fired

Tags: slickgrid

I have a slickgrid that, in the 'onMouseEnter' event, I do the following:

- change the underlying css for the row in question
- call grid.invalidateRow()
- call grid.render()

These latter two calls are necessary for the new css classes to be reflected.  However, I then need to capture the onMouseLeave event, and it is not fired when I move my mouse away from the cell (or row), presumably because the call to invalidate/render has placed a new DOM element under my mouse, and it's no longer the one I initially "entered."

So I have two questions:

1. Is there another way to have the new css classes for a given cell be rendered without calling invalidateRow/render?
2. If not, is there another way to do this and still have the onMouseLeave event fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [setCellCssStyles](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#setCellCssStyles) function.

```
grid.onMouseEnter.subscribe(function(e, args){
    var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(e),
        param = {},
        columnCss = {};

      for(index in columns){
          var id = columns[index].id;
          columnCss[id] = 'my_highlighter_style'
      }
      param[cell.row] = columnCss
      args.grid.setCellCssStyles("row_highlighter", param);
  })
```

So the above changes the `background-color` of every cell of the `row` that has been moused into. In [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/gzY44/), the `mouseLeave` subscription performs a simple `console.log` to ensure it is still firing.

---

**Edit**: *fixed the external resource usages in the fiddle for cross-browser support*

Comment: Your fiddle didn't work (didn't recognize Slick). Also, in my experience, simply calling setCellCssStyles won't actually cause the new styles to be rendered. You also must call invalidateRow() and then render() to see the new classes.

Comment: Did you use Firefox? It'll only work in Firefox due to the external github resource mime type issue. There is supposed to be a solution for Chrome/IE to use them but the last time I set it up to "work" it still didn't for those browsers.

Comment: The problem is I didn't realize Slickgrid used the hash (reference) I passed in for clearing old styles. So when I made changes to the hash in my code, and then called setCellCssStyles, it used the (same) hash that had since been modified to 'clear' out the old styles. The fix was to do a deep clone of my hash before calling setCellCssStyles.