# SlickGrid row selection not highlighting all columns

Tags: sql, slickgrid

I'm using slickGrid and I'm having a problem with the row selection model.

I have a page with 3 grids - with values returned from 3 different queries.
When I click on a row in 2 of the sections, the row highlights fine - however, in one of the sections when I click a row then the first column isn't highlighted.

I played around by adding additional columns and found that in all 3 sections it doesn't highlight some columns.

I can't find how to solve this, nor do I know how to even make a work around - e.g. hightlight the row myself.

Has anyone come across this or can tell me how to highlight a row manually please?

Cheers.

Comment: [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050923/slickgrid-mouseleave-event-not-fired-when-row-invalidated-after-mouseenter-f/24092054#24092054) for an example of highlighting the row yourself.

Comment: seems a coding issue only.can you create some fiddle to show your problem? or post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to your css file:

```
.slick-cell.selected {
background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
```